# Where in Windows should a third party IME install to?

Tags: c#, windows, wix, ime, windows-10-universal

I am currently developing a phonetic IME for Cantonese, to be compatible with the Windows 10 Universal Platform. To begin, I am exploring the Microsoft sample here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Input-Method-Editor-IME-b1610980 before I scrape any dictionary data or contribute any code myself.
Functionally, my first step in development is to create an installer, which I plan to do using Windows Installer XML.  Since IMEs are rare but serve a central and unique function, I am not quite sure how and where they should be installed.
Having explored other third-party IMEs before, I know that Program Files is not the correct destination.  Where should I use WiX to install .exes, and where?  Are there any other important steps I am missing?  I intend for my IME to be compatible with both Windows 10 and Windows 10 Mobile, though with a few differences between physical and touch keyboard inputs, if possible.